# Running WatiN tests with ReSharper testrunner

Tags: nunit, resharper, watin

I'm getting started with WatiN to test my web interface. The problem I'm having is the following:
When I start the tests from within TestDriven.net, I have no problem. If I use the ReSharper test runner, I get this predictable AppartmentState exception.

I tried using the different options described here: http://watin.sourceforge.net/apartmentstateinfo.html#testdriven. Nothing helps.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've use Resharper test runner in most of my watin test projects. To get it to work use the same method as for nunit:

http://watin.sourceforge.net/apartmentstateinfo.html#nunit

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <NUnit>
    <TestRunner>
      <!-- Valid values are STA,MTA. Others ignored. -->
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
    </TestRunner>
  </NUnit>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I can tell that nUnit/Resharper is seeing the .config file because its pulling some custom values from the appSettings section correctly.  It just doesn't seem to see the ApartmentState or set it correctly for the runner.

Answer (score 1):

With NUnit 2.5, [RequiresSTA](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=requiresSTA&r=2.5) attribute should be the tool of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Using Resharper 5.1 with VisualStudio 2010 Ultimate I found that I needed to change my Resharper options to disable "Shadow-copy assemblies being tested" (found in Resharper --> Options --> Tools --> Unit Testing).
Additionally, I also found that the correct naming for the config file is the one which includes the dll extension (so: assemblyname.dll.config).